# Why do we want to find asymptotic distribution?

Tags: probability-theory

I am studying probability theory and have a question about the use of Central Limit Theorem. Suppose we know $\bar X_n$ converges in probability to a constant $\mu$. Then doesn't that mean that it converges in distribution to $\mu$? Why do we need the Central Limit Theorem for asymptotic distribution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right that if $\bar X_n$ converges to $\mu$ in probability then it converges to $\mu$ in distribution, because convergence in probability always implies convergence in distribution.

However, knowing that the empirical mean converges to $\mu$ does not tell us anything about the rate at which this convergence happens, or in other words it doesn't tell us how much $\bar X_n$ fluctuates around $\mu$ for any given $n$.
This is the information the Central Limit Theorem gives us : it tells us that as $n$ goes to infinity, $\bar X_n $ tends to have the same distribution as $ \mathcal N(\mu,\frac{\sigma^2}{n})$ (assuming i.i.d $X_i$ of variance $\sigma^2$).